# Game Development: Flex or Flash IDE?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Which would be more comprehensive for game development?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends.

- Are you working by yourself or in a
  team ?
- Are you more a designer or a
  developer ?
- What's your level of comfort with
  actionscript ?

If you're just **starting with actionscript**, you're somewhat
**comfortable with the Flash IDE** and you want to make fun indy
games for people to bash buttons and destroy mice, go with **Flash**.
The look will weigh more at this stage and interaction will be simpler.
Never the less you can **create some addictive games with very simple interaction**.

If you're **more of a developer**, I would suggest using **Flash to generate your assets**
(characters, animations, etc.), or have your designer do that for you,
but use a **proper IDE to write your code**. 
As *Flemish Bee Cycle* mentioned, you can try **Flex Builder** or if you're on a **PC**, 
**Flash Develop** is an awesome IDE( free, lightweight, fast )
You could try to write you're own mini game engine, or use an existing one, like the [PushButtonEngine](http://pushbuttonengine.com/).

As far as I can see SWF is the dominant output for online games:

- [Miniclip](http://www.miniclip.com/games/en/)
- [Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/)
- [Nonoba](http://www.nonoba.com/)
- [MochiMedia](http://www.mochimedia.com/)
- [FlashGameLicense](http://www.flashgamelicense.com/)

HTH

Answer (score 5):

Use Flash for games. Games involve more animations (suits flash) than data driven user interface controls (suits flex).

Answer (score 4):

Since [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5) is the future, you might also want to check out [**Processing.js**](http://processingjs.org/exhibition), if you don't mind considering alternatives to Flash.

> Processing.js uses Javascript to draw
>   shapes and manipulate images on the
>   [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5) Canvas element. The code is
>   light-weight, simple to learn and
>   makes an ideal tool for visualizing
>   data, creating user-interfaces and
>   developing web-based games.

HTML5 aims to reduce the need for proprietary plug-in-based technologies such as Adobe Flash, Microsoft Silverlight, and Sun JavaFX. ([Wikipedia: HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html5))

In this case, you would have a vast choice of Editors or IDEs.

Comment: One problem with HTML5 and Javascript will be that you're sharing all the hard work (your code) with everyone.

Comment: There's always obfuscation, and a few other ways to limit this.

Comment: Yes, in my opinion, you can make JavaScript so difficult to reverse-engineer by code inspection, that it would be easier to re-develop it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Do the code in Flash Builder, as it is a better tool for coding; and the graphic resources in Flash.

Answer (score 1):

flash is aimed at designers.

flex is aimed at programmers

so it depends on your function in the game team.

Answer (score 1):

The editor in Flash is terrible. Flex Builder is based off of Eclipse, so if you're used to / or like Eclipse, you'll probably like Flex Builder. But I'd say neither, and give http://www.flashdevelop.org a try.

Comment: You can use Flex Builder to develop a Flash-only (no Flex) application. To stress this point, Adobe has renamed the tool Flash Builder for future versions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex as there are many inbuilt UIComponents for Tabs and mobile phones.It reduces overhead of many design like like touch scroller.It is better for game development in terms of programmer