# JavaFX vs Flash, which is good to make online game

Tags: java, flash, javafx

I am going to create a online game, so what is better, JavaFX or Flash?

Comment: Not so sure about JavaFX(http://java.dzone.com/articles/oracle-discontinue-javafx)...I'd say Flash...use Flash IDE for assets/animation, but a proper IDE for programming(flashdevelop/flash builder/fdt/intelliJ/etc.)...have a look here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011806/game-development-flex-or-flash-ide/2012410#2012410

Comment: @George Profenza Note that is just the JavaFX **Script** component of JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

For now use Flash as Oracle released the *beta* version for JavaFX for the Linux and OpenSolaris platforms.

Systems requirements [here](http://download.oracle.com/javafx/1.2/reference/system-requirements/system-requirements-1-2.html#javafxsdk):

Comment: JavaFX runs fine on Linux with a recent Java installed and I guess the number of people playing online games on OpenSolaris can be counted on the fingers of a single hand, especially now Oracle retracted support from the project.

Answer (score 0):

An "online game" is a bit vague, so it's difficult to give an accurate answer... do you mean a game that's played on your browser and/or a multiplayer game ?

it's a difficult question : some say HTML5 means the death of Flash - it is probably way too soon to tell. Java FX could be fine, though you'd need to check Oracle policy. I find it easier to find tutorials, resources, advices for flash, much more difficult to find it for Java FX.

Java + JMonkey give impressive result, including online games. I'd look into that.

Answer (score 0):

well the current JavaFX 1.3 is not being continued anymore. Oracle is working on the JavaFX 2, which is quite different from the current version (no JavaFX script language anymore!) and will be released late in 2010.
So I do not recommend you on starting with the dying JavaFX 1.3...

See the currently released roadmap of *JavaFX.com/roadmap*
Here the analysis of the JavaOne 2010 about the NEW JavaFX: http://java.dzone.com/articles/javaone-2010-alternative-jvm

So better go with Flash or even some other technologies...